# Loading DLL to user defined address

Tags: c, memory, dll, loadlibrary, virtualalloc

How to load the DLL into user define memory address or is it possible to change the DLL address after loading the DLL using `loadlibrary()` function.

I have tried using `VirtualAllocEx()` to allocate the memory address and load DLL to the remote process. DLL is loading into the remote process but the address is not same.

```
//virtually allocating the memory address
DWORD *arg = (PDWORD)VirtualAllocEx(process, /*(LPVOID)0x81200000*/0, strlen(buffer), MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
if(arg == NULL) {
    return 1;
}

//Write the argument to LoadLibraryA to the process's newly allocated memory region.
int n = WriteProcessMemory(process, arg, buffer, strlen(buffer), NULL);
if(n == 0) {
    return 1;
}

//Inject our DLL into the process's address space.
HANDLE threadID = CreateRemoteThread(process, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)address, arg, NULL, NULL);
```

I have also tried using `rebaseimage()` function but memory address changing after loading the DLL.

```
//rebaseimage function to change the base address of the DLL
ret = ReBaseImage("WinMemoryDLL.dll","",TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,0,&OldImage,&OldImageBase,&NewImageSize,&NewImageBase,0);

hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("WinMemoryDLL.dll"));
```

Comment: The default load address in the DLL header is only a hint for the OS. WHY do you want to load the DLL to a specific address? What's wrong with the address the OS chose?

Comment: What is your goal ? Looks like a [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: In the code that loads the dll, add a call to `GetModuleHandle()` on it to get its actual load address and store the result somewhere that your monitor code can get to it, say in a mapped memory section.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that I can think of to require your DLL to load into a user defined address.  According to standard Windows programming practices, you should never rely on a DLL being loaded into a specific address.

If you need to access something from the DLL at runtime, use relative offsets.  You can use [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) at runtime to get the address of the module, and then add your relative offset to get the dynamic address of whatever you need.  You can also export a function and use GetProcAddress() to get the address of the function.  Both these methods work with ASLR enabled and is the proper way to do it.